# $\log(1＋x)∈\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$ can be expressed as infinite product

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logarithms, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

Let $p$ be a prime number. There is a well known product formula for $\log(1+X)$ as a power series in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$ . Namely letting $\Phi_n(X)=(1+X)^{p^n}-1$ and $Q_n(X)=\Phi_{n+1}(X)/p\Phi_n(X)$, then we have$$\log(1+X)=X\prod_{n\geq1}Q_n(X).$$.

How can I prove this?

Pdf I'm reading reads both sides have exactly the same zeros, and up to a constant this completely determines a power series in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$ by the **weierstrass approximation theorem**. But I cannot figure out how and which statement we apply to this problem.

Another way or reference is also appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know what the zeros of the function $\log(1+X)$ are?

Comment: I don't know what they are. But if this formula is correct, it is all primitive roots of $x^{p^{I＋1}}＝1$ where $i≧0$.

Comment: Perhaps that’s your problem. Say $K$ is a $p$-adic field, perhaps highly ramified over $\Bbb Q_p$, and its ring of integers is $\mathcal O_K$, this with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak M_K$. You have to see that on the group $1+\mathfrak M_K$, the logarithm is a **homomorphism** to the additive group $K^+$. This is the case no matter how large $K$ is, preferably finite over $\Bbb Q_p$. Note that the complex logarithm is *not* a homomorphism, ’cause it’s not defined on a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $a\in p^2\Bbb{Z}_p$, write $1+a=\exp(b)$, we have
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{(1+a)^{p^k}-1}{p^k}=\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\exp(p^k b)-1}{p^k} = 
\lim_{k\to \infty} b + O(p^k) = b= \log(1+a)$$
So the infinite product and $\log(1+X)$ agree as functions $p^2\Bbb{Z}_p\to \Bbb{Z}_p$, which is a good start.